# Cannot drag and drop on Drools web process designer

Tags: jbpm, drools-guvnor

I just switch from Eclipse GRE to create process to Drools Web Process Designer, but I found an early bump. After creating my first BPMN2 process in the Global area I am not able to drag and drop from the Shape Repository into the canvas. If I drag the start event, it shows on the pointer, as soon as I pass the line to the canvas it gives me a green check, but when I release on the canvas the visual representation of the element goes back to the shape menu. This happens with most of the elements, but not with the Connecting Objects -> Sequence Flow, which does appear in the canvas.

I been searching for tutorials on how to do my first process, but all of them just say "Drag and Drop a X element", which I cannot do.

Do I have to enable editing before or something?

Answer (score 0):

That's an issue with Chrome if I don't remember wrong, please try with a different browser or with a different version of Chrome (the one that you are using is likely to have a bug related with svg files).

Regards

Answer (score 0):

//add directly into the html file or create kind of fixtures.js

```
if (!Document.prototype.createAttributeNS) {
Document.prototype.createAttributeNS = function(namespaceURI,
        qualifiedName) {
    var dummy = this.createElement('dummy');
    dummy.setAttributeNS(namespaceURI, qualifiedName, '');
    var attr = dummy.attributes[0];
    dummy.removeAttributeNode(attr);
    return attr;
};
```

}`if (!Element.prototype.setAttributeNodeNS) {
    Element.prototype.setAttributeNodeNS = Element.prototype.setAttributeNode;
}`